# select max value for each category with same unique key

Tags: sql, sqlite, max

here is part of my table, I show it by sorting value1

```
     uniquekey  city    test2     test3                     value1
0     001         NYC  40.724159 -73.754968                      32
1     002         NYC  40.753028 -73.921620                      22
2     003         LAX  40.845642 -73.902110                      20
3     003         LAX  40.845642 -73.902110                      19
4     002         NYC  40.753028 -73.921620                      18
5     004         LAX  40.870346 -73.904400                      17
6     005         LAX  40.849560 -73.834010                      17
7     006         LAX  40.851080 -73.848611                      17
8     002         NYC  40.753028 -73.921620                      16
9     007         NYC  40.762978 -73.831980                      16
```

I expect to return the highest value1 for city NYC and the highest value1 for city LAX.

The tricky thing here is that it is not an easy problem to show row 0 and 2 because **there are several rows have same uniquekey**, i.e for NYC row 1, 4, 8, for LAX row 2 and 3.

The expected output should be

```
    city    test2       test3                        max(value1)
0   NYC  40.724159 -73.754968                           66   <----32+18+16
1   LAX  40.845642 -73.902110                           39   <----20+19
```

here is my code

```
query = '''
select city, test2, test3, max(value1)
from nypd
where city IN ('NYC','LAX')
group by city
order by value1 DESC
'''
```

it only shows the top 2 ones:

```
    city    test2       test3                        max(value1)
0   NYC  40.724159 -73.754968                           32
1   LAX  40.845642 -73.902110                           20
```

Comment: Either your expected result is incorrect, or your accepted answer is wrong.  Actually, neither answer gives your expected result.  So, which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to aggregate to get the sum per `uniquekey`, `city`, `test2` and `test3` combination.

Then, to get the ones with the highest sum per city you could filter for the `row_number()` window function partitioning by city and ordering by the sum descending being `1`.

```
SELECT city,
       test2,
       test3,
       value1
       FROM (SELECT city,
                    test2,
                    test3,
                    sum(value1) value1,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY city
                                       ORDER BY sum(value1) DESC) rn
                    FROM nypd
                    WHERE city IN ('NYC', 'LAX')
                    GROUP BY uniquekey,
                             city,
                             test2,
                             test3) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

However older versions prior 3.25.0 of SQLite don't support `row_number()`. Here you can use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery checking for the existence of sums that are greater than the current sum or, in case of a tie, check for the `uniquekey` of the other row to be greater. The aggregation can be put in a CTE so it doesn't need to be repeated in the subquery.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT uniquekey,
       city,
       test2,
       test3,
       sum(value1) value1
       FROM nypd
       WHERE city IN ('NYC', 'LAX')
       GROUP BY uniquekey,
                city,
                test2,
                test3
)
SELECT c1.city,
       c1.test2,
       c1.test3,
       c1.value1
       FROM cte c1
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM cte c2
                                     WHERE c2.city = c1.city
                                          AND (c2.value1 > c1.value1
                                                OR c2.value1 = c1.value1
                                                   AND c2.uniquekey > c1.uniquekey));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select n.city, n.lat, n.long, sum(n.value1)
from nypd n
where n1.uniquekey = (select max(n2.uniquekey)
                      from nypd n2
                      where n2.city = n.city
                     )
group by n.city, n.lat, n.long;
```